# regex remove digits after a dot

Tags: r, regex

I'm trying to remove numbers after the dot so that `711.50` becomes `711` without changing the rest of the string. I have some code but it isn't working properly.

```
str <- "1,300 711.50 1300"
gsub("\\.\\d+$", "", str)
```

Desired output: `"1,300 711 1300"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `$` in `"\\.\\d+$"` requires the repeated digits after the literal `.` to finish *at the end of a line*. But you have `1300` after `711.50`, so the regular expression does not match the string. Remove the `$` and it works as expected:

```
str <- "1,300 711.50 1300"
gsub("\\.\\d+", "", str)
```

(Your original regular expression would work if your input `str` was `"1,300 711.50"`, with the `.50` at the end of the line)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Just a follow-up: how do I remove all dots in a string such as `str <- 230 20 97. 20.. 30... 20` I have this `str_replace(x, "[.]", "")` but it only captures the first dot, while I want to get rid of all of them.

Comment: @Misha, is it a vector which you are creating whose values should be replaced? because when I create a simple vector and run either mine or CertainPerformance's code is working for me.